# "dimension" and "parameter" equivalent commands in C

Tags: c, fortran

I'm not too familiar with writing C but I'm currently translating some code from FORTRAN to C.  I understand the meaning of both but I'm unsure how to write it in C.  Here's a small clipping of my code in Fortran:

```
program main
      parameter (g=9.8,nx=102,ny=100,r13=1./3.,r23=2./3.)
      dimension u0(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3),ux(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3)
      dimension uy(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3),uxx(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3)
      dimension uxy(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3),uyy(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parameter (g=9.8,nx=102,ny=100,r13=1./3.,r23=2./3.)
```

can be translated to `#define` statements.

```
#define g 9.8
#define nx 102
#define ny 100
#define r13 (1./3.)
#define r23 (2./3.)
```

And

```
dimension u0(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3),ux(0:nx+1,0:ny+1,3)
```

can be translated to:

```
double u0[nx+2][ny+2][3];
double u1[nx+2][ny+2][3];
```

You have to very careful about the use of indices though. In FORTRAN, `u0(0, 0, 3)` is a valid item. In C, you have to use `u0[0][0][2]` to access the corresponding item.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of close - assumes a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays:

```
const double g = 9.8;
const int nx = 102;
const int ny = 100;
const double r13 = 1.0/3.0;
const double r23 = 2.0/3.0;

int main( void )
{
   int u0[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   int ux[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   int uy[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   int uxx[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   int uxy[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   int uyy[nx+2][ny+2][3];
   ...
}
```

Note that arrays in C don't allow arbitrary indexing; they *always* start from 0, so an `N`-element array is *always* indexed from 0 to `N`-1.  Thus, if you want an array indexed from 0 to 103, you must declare the array size as 104.

If you're using a compiler that doesn't support VLAs, then array dimensions must be specified with compile-time constant expressions.  Thus, `nx` and `ny` will have to be preprocessor macros instead of `const`-qualified variables, like so:

```
#define nx 102
#define ny 100
```

Declaring the other constants at file scope makes them visible to other translation units, which kind-of sort-of serves the same function as the `PARAMETER` statement.